# Center align text while there are other texts on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this may sound like a silly question but here goes
I'd Like to Center Align a text while there are other text inside a div.

## HTML

```
 <div class="divisions" id="lightsBox">
    <h1> Lights Status </h1>

    <p class="divisionsText">Number of Lights On: </p> <p id="nLightsOn"></p> <br>
    <p class="divisionsText">Number of Lights Off: </p> <p id="nLightsOff"></p>


 </div>
```

## Javascript

```
 document.getElementById("lightsBox").style.opacity = 0.6;
 document.getElementById("lightsBox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
 var h = document.createElement("H1")               


 h.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Feature not avaliable"));
 h.style.verticleAlign = "middle";
 h.style.textAlign = "center";
 h.style.color ="red";
```

[image]

I want to Align the *"Feature not available"* text, in the middle of the div on top of other texts to look like this, (edited with ms paint :P)

[image]

Comment: margin and padding are your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using absolute positioning.

You can add to the parent "lightsBox" this style

```
position: relative
```

Then add to the h1 element you want to center this styles

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-100%);
text-align:center;
width: 100%;
```

Using JS would be something like this:

```
document.getElementById("lightsBox").style.position = "relative";
h.style.position = "absolute";
h.style.top = "50%";
h.style.transform = "translateY(-100%)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should target one of the paragraphs and then createTextNode for `"<h1>Feature not available</h1>"` in between them. Or you can always have the  there but with a display: none; and then show it once you need too.